# how can create files and how to implement code for read content into file and write content into file

Tags: android

hi  all how to implement code for Write content into a file &
read content from file  and how  create files and how can  to enter text in it to write and read files

help me any one of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't u just use SharedPreferences.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

This has some nice example code. Good luck :) http://huuah.com/android-writing-and-reading-files/